# PHP regex question

Tags: php, regex, url

I am looking for someone that can help me with a regex for the following.

I have this code: (have updated it)

```
<?php
$sitename = "http://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($sitename);
$language = "da";
$language = mysql_real_escape_string($language);
$pagename = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$pagename = mysql_real_escape_string($pagename);
$language1 = preg_replace("/$language/", "$1", "$pagename");
?>
```

I need a regex to strip the language from the url(sitename) - This now works

> How do I escape spesial characters?
>   The result from the above example
>   leaves me with //index.asp and not
>   with /index.asp

Basically what I want to do is to strip a constant (/da) from a URL:

the url will look like this http://www.domain.com/da/ or http://www.domain.com/da/folder/folder/folder/page.asp

I only need to take the da out of the url

How will I do this in php?

Thanks

Ok I seemed to have figured it out:

```
   <?php
$sitename = "http://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($sitename);
$language = "\/da";
$pagename = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$pagename = mysql_real_escape_string($pagename);
$language1 = preg_replace("/$language/", "$1", "$pagename");
?>
```

I only needed to remove this line:

```
 $language = mysql_real_escape_string($language);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Replace:**

```
$re = '/(?:\w+:\/\/[\w][\w.]+\/)(\w+)\//ui';
or this $re = '^(?:.*)\/(\w{2})\//ui';

$text = http://www.domain.com/ru/

preg_replace($re, 'ru', $text);

--> *http://www.domain.com/ru/*
```

---

### **Search:**

```
$re = '/(?<domain>\w+:\/\/[\w][\w.]+\/)(?<lang>\w+)\//ui';
or this $re = '^(?:.*)\/(?<lang>\w{2})\//ui';

$text = http://www.domain.com/ru/

preg_match($re, $text, $aMatches);

--> Array
(
    [0] => http://www.domain.com/da/
    [domain] => http://www.domain.com/
    [1] => http://www.domain.com/
    [lang] => da
    [2] => da
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post some real strings you want to parse (the question makes little sense with the code you post since you already have the data in the `$language` variable). Whatever, in PHP you can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) to split the URL into its components and then:

- [substr(..., -2)](http://php.net/substr) to extract the trailing letters (if fixed)
- [explode('/', ...)](http://php.net/explode) and [end()](http://php.net/end) to obtain the last fragment

The exact details depend on what your data looks like.

BTW, your JavaScript code will change `/data/en` into `/sitenameta/en` :-?